# График на стороне клиента

Tags: график, json, javascript

Каким образом можно построить график на js используя json массивы данных "Всего получается 2 массива. Посещения и просмотры". Данные берутся из некого файла stat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если разбирать json на стороне клиента, то работа будет в дальнейшем вестись, как с обычными объектами javascript. Это базовые знания - разбирайтесь.

Что касается графика, то здесь естественно проще использовать уже готовые решения. Где основная работа заключается в постановке данных. Я бы посоветовал http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

Перейдя по ссылке можно посмотреть демо, и там же на сайте ознакомиться с API.

Comment: мне интересна структура кода для вывода грфикап

Comment: кстати, highcharts при коммерческом использовании - платный, d3 ещё можно использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите мою реализацию графиков на javascript http://jsgadget.ru/jschart.html

Answer (score 0):

Для создания графика воспользуйтесь HTML5 Canvas API. Для использования возможностей Canvas в IE версий 7 и 8 можно воспользоваться библиотекой excanvas.js ([проект на гитхабе](https://github.com/arv/excanvas)).

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), библиотека позволяет генерировать неплохие графики на стороне клиента. Есть еще [d3js](http://d3js.org/). Думаю этого должно хватить, если не хотите использовать готовое и есть время, можно самому реализовать. Но думаю лучше воспользоваться этими библиотеками, вам необходимо только достать данные из ваших json-массивов и на основе этих данных сделать графики. 
P.S. Можно также воспользоваться библиотекой json2.js для работы с json ))